How to increase space between paragraphs within lists without increasing space between list items
Using enumitem, the vertical space between items is itemsep + parsep.  How can the space between paragraphs (parsep) be increased without increasing the vertical space between items?

Can you provide an MWE? Why can't you reduce itemsep to compensate?

@cfr Good point.  But what if you want the space between items to be the "default" value (that is, the space when parsep is set to its own default of zero)?  Without knowing this value, how do you know how much to compensate?

If you provide code to play with, I'll see if I can get it to work using the variable. Don't know if that's possible off-hand.

Compute first the value to pass to itemsep using the default values of \itemsep and \parsep together with the desired value for \parsep.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\newparsep}
\setlength{\newparsep}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[
  itemsep=\glueexpr\itemsep+\parsep-\newparsep\relax,
  parsep=\newparsep,
]

\item \lipsum[1][1]\par\lipsum[1][2]

\item \lipsum[2][1]\par\lipsum[2][2]

\end{itemize}

\end{document}


Output without the settings:


If I understand this correctly, the \newparseps will cancel under \itemsep+\parsep, and the resulting space between items will be \itemsep+\parsep, as usual.  But \parsep has been redefined to \newparsep, so I don't understand how this works.  Could you please explain?

@steven_nevets The parameters are set in the order they’re presented. When itemsep is evaluated, we can use the current values, \itemsep and \parsep, which I subtract the desired value of parsep from. Thus, after also setting parsep, the value of \itemsep+\parsep will be as at startup. These parameters are not macros.
